# For loop to iterate over IP & hostnames

Tags: bash

Esteemed Colleagues,

I am looking for better bash way/method  to create a loop to fit my requirement, i have a command called "ldaphost" which assigns an IP address to a host with the below provided syntex.

**Example:**

```
$ ldaphost --insert  "192.168.1.1 mytestvm1"
```

Though i have below for loop which is working for me as a work around as of now, Moreover looking an expert and  better neat solution for the same with bash or shell.

**Requirement is:**

I have to an IP range from `192.168.1.1` to `192.168.1.254` and in the same format hostnames as `mytestvm1`  to `mytestvm254` which i'm adding into my below script.

```
#!/bin/bash

for ip in {1..254}
do
 ldaphost --insert "192.168.1.${ip} mytestvm${ip}"
done
```

One more thing i would like know if we can add the password as a pre answer into script as this is asking password on every iteration..

```
bash-4.1$ cat reservHost.sh
#!/bin/bash
for ((i = 13 i <= 15; i++)); do
     ldaphost --insert "1192.168.1.$i mytestvm$i"
done

bash-4.1$ ./reservHost.sh
Password:
Inserted: 192.168.1.13 mytestvm13
Password:
Inserted: 192.168.1.14 mytestvm14
```

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is?

Comment: I really do not think there is a better way that is not completely unreadable and maintainable. The code you provided seems to be as good as it is going to get. Nice job!

Comment: @Chiru    I'm looking forward if there is better way in bash to achieve  the same script which i have created . May be having values like IP & Hostname in arrays, i'm just learner.

Comment: @TomFenech    Hey that was just a typo here.. corrected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You're doing it right, as is: brace expansion and a loop are clear, concise, and efficient.**

As @chepner noted, you might have more efficient looping by using a C-style construct:

```
for ((i = 1; i <= 254; i++)); do
     ldaphost --insert "192.168.1.$i mytestvm$i"
done
```

You might also choose to use `xargs` instead of loops:

```
xargs -a<(echo -n {1..254}) -INNN -d' ' -n1 ldaphost --insert "192.168.1.NNN mytestvmNNN"
```

A benefit of `xargs` over `for` is that this approach is *trivially* parallelizable: just add `-P 0` to the xargs command line to run as many as are possible.

Comment: A C-style for loop would be more efficient, since it doesn't require generating the full sequence before starting the loop body. For only 255 values, though, it's not a big deal.

Comment: Well, with a Bash loop you can also make it parallel easily by appending `&` to the command inside the loop, though this will cause 254 processes to be created (which probably is not that bad as far as a modern OS/computer is concerned).

Comment: The efficiency gain due to the loop is very likely to be negligible compared to the cost of executing ldaphost, so I would say go with whatever syntax you prefer writing/debugging/maintaining.

Comment: @Fred It's more an issue of latency and memory usage; for a large sequence, there can be a noticeable delay before the first iteration begins.

Comment: @bishop    , I just forgot to add if we can put the password into the script as a pre answer So, i do not need to type this every-time as its asking over every iteration. I just updated the post..

Comment: @bishop    should i raise another thread for that, would appreciate your advise.

Comment: @Karn Great, link to that other question as a comment in this question and please accept any answer on this question that satisfies.

Comment: @bishop   sure accepted, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165612/how-to-provide-passwords-to-confirm-prompts-while-running-script