# How to provide passwords to confirm prompts while running script

Tags: shell

How automatically provide the password on the prompts while running a script.
I have Below script which is adding IP and Hostname , So, while i run , this used to prompts for password on the window on each iteration..

Would appreciate any help..

```
bash-4.1$ cat reservHost.sh
#!/bin/bash
for ((i = 13 i <= 15; i++)); do
     ldaphost --insert "1192.168.1.$i mytestvm$i"
done

bash-4.1$ ./reservHost.sh
Password:
Inserted: 192.168.1.13 mytestvm13
Password:
Inserted: 192.168.1.14 mytestvm14
```

Comment: Ideally, you *don't*. For instance, if your LDAP site uses Kerberos for authentication, then you just rely on having a valid ticket created before the script can be run at all, and let that ticket authenticate you to the server.

Comment: Similarly, doing a bunch of LDAP changes can typically be done by combining them into a single LDIF, so that one LDIF can be executed all at once, rather than re-authenticating over and over again.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy    I understand that We can have multiple attribute into the LDIF and run at one go providing the password once to pass over and all set, but here this "ldaphost" which is itself a script based on perl but i dont have access to hardcode the password over there hence i need this script to run to accomplish the task.

Comment: Who's telling you to hardcode a password? I'm certainly not. Rather, I'm telling you to either (1) select an authentication method (such as Kerberos) with an idea of an authenticated *session*, or (2) rewrite your ldaphost script to be able to run with multiple `--insert` arguments in a single pass, so it only needs to accept credentials once.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy    no one, just my own thought and for my own use.

Comment: ...dealing with passwords is messy: You can't pass them on the command line, because any user on the system can read the command line off any app. You can *sometimes* pass them on the environment -- on some operating systems environment variables are protected against other users snooping, and on some they aren't. There are `expect`-type approaches, but to use them securely you need to use `mprotect()` to prevent the process from being paged out to disk, and to have a kernel that'll properly clear deallocated memory before other apps can use it.

Comment: BTW, what happens if you call `ldaphost` with multiple `--insert` arguments on one command line? If it only prompts once for as many inserts as you have, then there's an easy solution: Put them all on one command line (easy to build with a loop), and then you only have one prompt.

Comment: (Also, a lot of the possible approaches -- passing a file descriptor to read the password from, passing in an environment variable, etc -- depend on how your `ldaphost` tool is written, and, well, we haven't seen it).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy   i agreed dealing with passwords is messy, but it really not uses multiple `--insert` option. This tool is written in perl which i dont know much :( appreciate you inputs and suggestions ..